# Clojure equivalent to Python doctest?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, marginalia

Python doctests associate simple tests with the source code (in Python they are in the function documentation).  [More info and examples here](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html).

Is there anything similar for Clojure?

I am aware of unit tests with `clojure.test`, but looking for something more closely integrated with the source (typically unit tests are in different files; here I want to have the test "inside" the `defn`).

Searching around I found [this](https://github.com/Kobold/clj-doc-test), but it seems very un-lispy (the tests are in actual text, like Python - surely a macro that extends `defn` would be preferable?).

Or perhaps there is some other way to solve the general problem, which is that I have some tests (generally simple things that demonstrate basic properties of the function) that would be better included with the documentation (I am using [marginalia](http://fogus.me/fun/marginalia/)) than in separate unit test files.

*update*  Here's an example: I have a function that calculates the (manhattan) distance (in pixels) from a rectangle of pixels to the centre of the image.  That sounds simple, but is complicated by things like the difference in meaning of "centre" for images with odd or even numbers of pixels on sides, or which part of the block you measure from.  So I had to write some tests just to get the code straight.  And now I look at the docs and really it would be best if the docs included those tests because they explain better than words what the function does...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

and the test flag in metadata, http://clojure.org/special_forms

```
(defn
 ^{:doc "mymax [xs+] gets the maximum value in xs using > "
   :test (fn []
             (assert (= 42  (mymax 2 42 5 4))))
   :user/comment "this is the best fn ever!"}
  mymax
  ([x] x)
  ([x y] (if (> x y) x y))
  ([x y & more]
   (reduce mymax (mymax x y) more)))

user=> (test #'mymax)
:ok
user=> (doc test)
-------------------------
clojure.core/test
([v])
  test [v] finds fn at key :test in var metadata and calls it,
  presuming failure will throw exception
nil
```

Comment: looks perfect!  had no idea that existed.  but how do you run it? does lein test call it?

Comment: use test function: (test #'mymax), doc: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/test

Answer (score 2):

How about :pre and :post expressions? 
http://blog.fogus.me/2009/12/21/clojures-pre-and-post/

Comment: oh that's cute and very close, but it doesn't let me give specific examples.  i'll add an example to the question that might show better what i am looking for.

Comment: `:pre` and `:post` conditions are good for contracts, not so good for tests.